# Not getting an IP address when using Bridged-Adapter in Virtual Box when using WiFi

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I am using `Virtual Box v 4.3.6` on a `Mac OS X` host.

I am trying to run a Linux VM on it and I have set it up to use Bridged Adapter.

When the host is connected to WiFi i never get an IP address for the VM. But when the host is connected to a Wired Network I will get an IP address for the VM.

What could possibly be wrong with my setup? How do I diagnose the problem in my setup?

Comment: Did you add the wi-fi connection as a network adapter in the VirtualBox network settings? Could you post the results of `ifconfig`?